# What is better for performances: IN or OR

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, request

I need to do a request that check if a column value is either 2117 or 0.

Currently, I do this with a OR

```
select [...] AND (account_id = 2117 OR account_id = 0) AND [...]
```

Since I'm facing performance issues, I was wandering whether it wouldn't be better to do

```
select [...] AND account_id IN (0, 2117) AND [...]
```

Explain command gives similar results in both cases. So, maybe it's more about optimizing the parsing phase than anything else. Or maybe those two ways are totally equivalent and optimized away by mySQL and I should just not care.

On the mySQL website, they talk about the OR optimization like that:

> Use x = ANY (table containing (1,2)) rather than x=1 OR x=2.

But I didn't get the syntax right or even understand why.

What do you think?

Comment: As far as I remember, rule-based query optimization in MySQL should convert the first and second query into same structure, so I wouldn't expect any big improvement in this area at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no contest here... `IN` is *always* much, much better.

The reason is that databases won't use an index with an `OR`, but will use an index with `IN`.

Changing `OR` to `IN` is usually the first optimization I make to queries.

Comment: Do you have a reference (or test data) to show that this is true? `EXPLAIN` for a very simple test showed that neither case is optimized and involved a table scan.

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing. My test shows no difference (on small amount of data). I found reference to that in a mysql documentation comments (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) but it looks like it's true for mysql 3.x but not for 4.x. So, maybe, you just kept this habit from that version.

Comment: It would make sense for this to be true; IN restricts tests to (not) all-equal and involves just one column, while OR can involve all manner of columns and conditions. With the restrictions placed by IN, the db engine surely could make some optimisations.

Comment: @halfer yep, it would make sense. But I wonder if it's just a matter of parsing than anything else. Once mySQL find out that the OR is done on the same column, it should be able to optimize away, especially since the OR looks like: [...] AND (a.account_id=0 OR a.account_id=2217) AND [...]. (See the parenthesis)

Comment: I did some benchmark on a 200K rows table and saw no significant difference, nothing worth of doing the change

Comment: It seems I am out of date... I ran an explain and it shows no difference. I swear it used to be the case! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try and run a heavy benchmark? If theres a noticable difference then opt for the better option, otherwise just use "OR" for readability. Maybe the source code would yield some useful answers, but that might be outside the scope of efficiency.

Comment: Yes, it's outside the scope. And about efficiency, My production database is crawling right now. I have requests that take up to 2 minutes. So, I don't have the time to properly setup a benchmark. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In it typically easier to read and handle by the engine... However, that said based on some limited number.  You don't want to an IN or OR with 20+ IDs (typically).  When you get into a situation where there are a bunch of numbers, create a table (temp table even) an insert the values you want to join based on, then use that as the basis of a SQL-join for your results.  Offers better flexibility when dealing with larger selections of data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Here, I'm only dealing with two value: either 0 or the account_id of the currently loggedin user

Comment: @Thomas, in that case, IN is just as easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there might be a difference with lots of elements, but not with two. I'd be more inclined to tune indexes or to look at the table architecture, to find worthwhile performance improvements.

Comment: I tried both on a multi-hundred thousand rows table with proper indexes and nothing shows